# Outlook 2013: add contact from mail but all fields remain empty

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, contacts

I've got a Windows 10 machine with Office 2013. When I open an e-mail, click one of the contacts in an address field and choose 'add to contacts' this opens the new contact card but leaves all fields empty.

If I do the same on a Windows 7 machine with Office 2013 all fields are populated in advance.

Comment: Please add examples and screenshots of what you are doing. Where are the fields that should have been added?

Comment: Is it possible that these fields were hidden by a registry key such as described in [this link](https://www.slipstick.com/exchange/hiding-global-address-book-fields/)?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I cannot reproduce this with Outlook 2013. When from the Global Address List I right click and select **Add to contact**, it brings up all the user's attributes from the GAL.

1. **I suspect** that the Outlook profile with the problem needs to *uncheck* the "**Use Cached Exchange Mode**" and whatever is cached for that email from the GAL is not up to date.

   To be thorough with this option in troubleshooting, uncheck "**Use Cached Exchange Mode**" and then restart Outlook. I'd even give it a few minutes and try again to see if it'll populate the attributes from the GAL address book and not a locally cached copy without the attributes.

   [image]

   <sub>[Image Source](https://support.content.office.net/en-us/media/541adecb-8beb-49a9-a05e-61a6f5ac1681.jpg)</sub>
2. **Furthermore, if the cached exchange mode toggle does not help**, it could be a corrupted Outlook profile. So if you [add an additional account to Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-an-email-account-to-outlook-6e27792a-9267-4aa4-8bb6-c84ef146101b) on the machine with the trouble and give it a different profile name but link it to the same user account, test from it and see if it has the issue *not using Exchange cached mode*.

   [image]

   <sub>[Image Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-an-email-account-to-outlook-6e27792a-9267-4aa4-8bb6-c84ef146101b)</sub>

   I know Exchange cached mode is supposed to keep the local cache sync'd with the email server, but I know that does not always happen and people cannot see new accounts in the GAL so this may be a problem using cached mode and that bug too perhaps.
3. **Lastly, there is a way to run a repair on an Outlook profile** so follow one of the steps as outlined on the [Repair Outlook Profile](https://kb.uwm.edu/uwmhd/page.php?id=58888) post too for an additional thing to try in troubleshooting this issue.

   [image]

---

### Supporting Resources

- [Turn on Cached Exchange Mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/turn-on-cached-exchange-mode-7885af08-9a60-4ec3-850a-e221c1ed0c1c)
- [Add an Account to Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-an-email-account-to-outlook-6e27792a-9267-4aa4-8bb6-c84ef146101b)
- [Create an Outlook Profile](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-an-outlook-profile-f544c1ba-3352-4b3b-be0b-8d42a540459d)
- [Repair Outlook Profile](https://kb.uwm.edu/uwmhd/page.php?id=58888)